# lost between RDBMS, JCR, CMIS

Tags: java, alfresco, jcr, cmis, modeshape

I have to start a new project for managing data generated from workflow lab.
The generated data is hierarchical and contains structured and none structured data.
Large part of the data will be office file and images. Querying the content of office and pdf document is required.

I first started learning CMIS 1.1. But I can't find any implementation of it. Alfresco seems to be the best but do not implement CMIS 1.1 yet.

ModeShape looks ok. But I don't know if it's popular enough or not. I am afraid that JBoss will drop it as what they did with Seam 2.

RDBMS are not very good for managing and querying files.

So, what technology to choose for this type project?

I have a good experience in javaEE + RDBMS development.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Generally a Document Management System would make an excellent choice for this solution.

Depending on the level of effort you plan on spending on the project, you may want to [explore Alfresco's architecture](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/alfresco-arch-about.html) and take advantage of the underlying [Spring MVC Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) that supports the [Alfresco Share](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/02/26/creating-custom-share-widgets/) web application.

From [this post on the Alfresco Forums](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/alfresco-cmis-11-compliant-12132013-1009), Alfresco is CMIS 1.1 Compliant. You should be able to access CMIS 1.1 from Alfresco through the following URL: http://example.com:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom

For more information on Alfresco CMIS: http://www.alfresco.com/cmis

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [**Apache Jackarabbit**](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/) which is the reference implementation of the Java Content Repository specification (JSR-170).
It supports versioning, searching, transactions and is a suitable framework for Content Driven Application that rely on structured hierarchical data.
You may also take a look at [**Apache Sling**](https://sling.apache.org/), a framework for building web application based on Apache Jackarabbit.

BR.

Comment: I have an application I'm working on called meta64.com, which is built using Java, JavaScript, Google Polymer, TypeScript, JQuery, that is built on the latest Jackrabbit Oak JCR (backed by MongoDB storage), which uses Spring on the back end, which is a unique combination of all the latest technologies (IMO of course). Builds as a SpringBoot app, and is essentially a "Social Sharing" application. A Tree Structure in the cloud for sharing any kind of content, and collaborative editing. This app is OpenSource and on GitHub and may be worth at least looking at regarding how JCR can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Actually RDBMS is a very good solution for binary data e.g. Oracle DBF http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_fs.htm#ADLOB45990 it provides plsql content store API out of the box. 
CMIS protocol is similar to JCR API concepts but JCR is not necessary to implement CMIS. We normally store metadata on RDBMS and binary files on raw file system because good RDBMS implementation is too expensive. If licensing costs is not an issue for your project then good RDBMS should be fine for binary data too.  See Apache Chemistry http://chemistry.apache.org/project/cmis.html for CMIS,  I use modified Fileshare repository implementation.

Comment: I can only use postgres as RDBMS. Is Fileshare repository OK for production?

Comment: Postgres stores all of blobs in the same pg_largeobject table and all of them will go to system table space, I think it is not usable as file system but you can mimic this table as user table and implement partitioning by yourself. Fileshare repository is not production ready too, it stores metadata on file system and it won't scale as content repository, you will need custom storage for metadata.